# bootstrap layout for form elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

could anyone please help in getting the below layout using HTML5 and bootstrap.
i want the Name label always on left and the Formatted checkbox always on right and the three textboxes share the remaining space evenly.[click here for required layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSzrM.jpg)

Code I tried

```html
<form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="FirstName">Name:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control inputText" id="txtFirstName" placeholder="First Name" name="txtFirstName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="MiddleName" class="sr-only">Middle Name:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control inputText" id="txtMiddleName" placeholder="Middle Name" name="txtMiddleName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="LastName" class="sr-only">Last Name:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control inputText" id="txtLastName" placeholder="Last Name" name="txtLastName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label><input type="checkbox"/>Formatted</label>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but I would suggest you look at this bootstrap page https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/